# Can't enter calculation in table

Tags: math-mode, tables

I'm kind of new to LaTeX and I want to put these 3 calculations in a table. But I'm getting errors

```
\begin{tabular}{ l | c | r }  
\begin{math} 
  \frac{9250}{7650} = 1,21 &
  \frac{10126}{7986} = 1,27 & 
  \frac{10210}{7850} = 1,30 
\end{math}
\end{tabular}
```

Maybe someone can see what is wrong?

The error:

```
Extra }, or forgotten $.
```

But I don't see where I might have forgotten that.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: If you use `,` as a "decimal dot", you should put it in braces to get correct spacing. Because `$1,27$` has a space after the comma and means "list of two numbers" whereas `$1{,}27$` has no space after the comma and means "one point twenty-seven" in some languages (not in English though).

Comment: Maybe you will also like the result of `\quad` and `\qquad`. Just put all your equations on one line between `\[ \]`, and seperate them by `\qquad` instead of `&`. I guess you will appreciate the result. (Tabulars are kind of evil.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add each cells  in math mode

```
    \begin{tabular}{ l | c | r } 
      $\frac{9250}{7650} = 1,21$  & 
      $\frac{10126}{7986} = 1,27$ &
      $\frac{10210}{7850} = 1,30$  
    \end{tabular}
```

You can also write `\begin{math}\frac{9250}{7650} = 1,21\end{math}` etc...

I think it's perhaps useful to read the mathmode.pdf of Herbert Voss [from here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/math/voss/mathmode)

Answer (score 9):

use an `array` anvironment instead of a tabular:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{ l c r }  
    \dfrac{9250}{7650} = 1,21 &
    \dfrac{10126}{7986} = 1,27 & \dfrac{10210}{7850} = 1,30 
\end{array}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: To clarify this answer (which in my eyes is the best): Array is designed for math straigtaway. Since the content of your table is math, you probably should consider `array` instead of `tabular`. Note that you should indead put {} around the commata, like `{,}`.

Comment: @jmc: The OP can use the [icomma](www.ctan.org/pkg/icomma) package to have proper spacing when using comma `,` as decimal separator.

Comment: @MartinHeller, Nice! I did not know that package. Since I am Dutch, it might come in helpful now and then.

Comment: it is also possible to redefine the symbols with `\DeclareMathSymbol`if one needs it for the whole document

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [the array package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) to specify macros to be applied at the beginning of each element with `>{\command}` and after each element `<{command}`. For example `>{\begin{math}}l<{\end{math}}` would typeset the column as math text and would left (`l`) align it (as in the first example below).

Alternatively, you could also define a `\newcolumntype{L}{>{\begin{math}}l<{\end{math}}}` and then just use `L` and that column would automatically be in math mode (as in the second example below).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\begin{math}}l<{\end{math}}}%
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\begin{math}}c<{\end{math}}}%
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\begin{math}}r<{\end{math}}}%


\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ 
    >{\begin{math}}l<{\end{math}} | 
    >{\begin{math}}c<{\end{math}} | 
    >{\begin{math}}r<{\end{math}}}  
    \frac{9250}{7650}  = 1,21 &
    \frac{10126}{7986} = 1,27 & \frac{10210}{7850} = 1,30 
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{L | C | R}  
    \frac{9250}{7650}  = 1,21 &
    \frac{10126}{7986} = 1,27 & \frac{10210}{7850} = 1,30 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```